Dynamics CRM- email safedescription column vs description column
I am currently working on archiving attachments and updating the sharing URL of the attachment in the description field of emails.
However, I have encountered an issue on some email forms where the SafeDescription column is displayed instead of the Description column.
The problem I am facing is that the SafeDescription column appears to truncate the URLs, whereas the Description column stores the full URLs correctly. This truncation is causing issues with the functionality of the links when they are accessed through the email form.
Could you please assist me in ensuring that the full URL stored in the Description column is displayed on the email forms instead of the truncated version in SafeDescription?
Example of full url in description column:
<a href='https://something.com/prod/file one.pdf?sv=2021-10-04'>file one.pdf</a>

Example of truncated url in safedescription column:
<a href='https://something.com/prod/file '>file one.pdf</a>

I am expecting that the full url is working on description column.
It seems that the safedescription column cannot be displayed on form.

Here is a response from Dynamics forum Where I posted my question:
"The URL should be encoded before."
Then I used the HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode() method to do that.
